# React GeoSuggest with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using this [React auto-suggest address component](https://github.com/ubilabs/react-geosuggest) like this:

```
<Geosuggest
  name="adresse"
  onSuggestSelect={this.onSuggestSelect}
  onBlur={this.onSuggestSelect}
  autoComplete="on"
/>
```

It works nicely but I'm wondering how can I render a Material UI input instead of the one rendered by the library.
Otherwise, is there any way for me to retrieve the `className` applied to an input? For instance: `MuiInput-input-72 MuiInput-inputSingleline-79`

Also, I'm using `next.js` so SSR is important so I can't easily play with `style` but `className` only.

Comment: What do you mean by this: "Otherwise, is there any way for me to retrieve the className applied to an input?".  Or is the question if you can get the class(es) of the input being used by the Geosuggest component?

Comment: For instance if you do this:
```import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
<TextField defaultValue="Hello World"/>```.
`Textfield` will already have a className applied to it. So using the same to style my component (without having to copy/paste all the styling of a material input manually)

Comment: I would also be interested in getting an answer to this question. @CyrilF Have you figured out how to? To add more information to this question, the React Material Template is http://material-ui-next.com/

Comment: I couldn't find a good way to use the react-geosuggest component with a material-ui input either. Instead I just customized the css of the geosuggest input to match my material-ui inputs. 

You can target the geosuggest input using the .geosuggest__input class that is automatically added to it.